# Quickblox Error : You are not owner of this object on API call to PUT /users/

Tags: quickblox

When i try to update user using REST API PUT request. I got an error "You are not owner of this object".

**Request :**

```
PUT /users/14055179.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.quickblox.com
Content-Type: application/json
QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0
QB-Token: 10b89fb07e0b871230d5c8ce662aa70e4429f761
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5d89f9ba-4da2-8ba2-5e82-0de2b57a2b3f

{"user": {"full_name": "hpmakwana"}}
```

**Response :**

```
{
  "errors": {
    "base": [
      "You are not owner of this object"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickblox provide two tyes of session :

1. Application session token (only READ rights)
2. User session token (READ+WRITE rights)

For Write we have to create **User session token**.

For More Details [click here](https://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Summary)